# Как запустить распаковку архива на удалённом сервере без прерывания при разрыве соединения

Tags: linux, bash, centos, 7z

На сервере лежит большой разрезанный 7ź архив , который распаковывается очень долго, можно ли запустить  его распаковку и отключиться от сервера, но чтобы распаковка не прерывалась?
И кстати это нормально что 7z архив размером в 1гиг распаковывается по 4 часа?

Comment: Про время распаковки задайте отдельный вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйся screen-ом. 
Наиболее частое ее применение - сворачивание в фон программ, которые сами этого не умеют, с возможностью последюущего возврата к ним. это может быть полезно при работе с программами, которые реализованы не в виде «демон+клиент», а единым целым, и не работают без запуска интерфейса.
Простейший запуск осуществляется командой:

```
screen
```

После чего можете запустить команд и свернуть screen.
Вот [здесь](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/screen) подробнее

Comment: Исправил коментарий!

Answer (score 3):

Например через [tmux](https://the-bosha.ru/2010/06/01/terminal-window-manager-tmux/):

```
$ tmux
# вводим команду распоковки и Enter
# Жмём Ctrl+b d - Отключаемся от сессии
```

Через 4 часа, подключаемся к серверу:

```
$ tmux attach
# Любуемся на вывод комманды
# Если уже закончилась - закрываем сессию Ctrl+d
```